# Leaflet and jQuery Mobile PhoneGap OnLoad Issue

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, leaflet

I am currently having an issue getting Leaflet to play nicely with jQuery Mobile / PhoneGap. I have created a map with my own custom tiles with a map on the second page in my mobile app. When I go to the page the map is sitting up in the top left of the container and if I zoom in most of the tiles are missing. If I refresh the page while testing in a browser it loads perfectly fine.

This has lead me to believe that the script is firing too early, I tested this by putting the map page as the first div that loads in the app and everything works perfectly - however this isn't ideal for the design. I believe the problem is how I am using onLoad="init()" in the body tag.

Here's the script for the map:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/leaflet.css" />
<script src="js/leaflet.js"></script>
<script>
function init() {
    var mapMinZoom = 0;
    var mapMaxZoom = 3;
    var map = L.map('map', {
      maxZoom: mapMaxZoom,
      minZoom: mapMinZoom,
      crs: L.CRS.Simple
    }).setView([0, 0], mapMaxZoom);

    var mapBounds = new L.LatLngBounds(
        map.unproject([0, 1536], mapMaxZoom),
        map.unproject([1536, 0], mapMaxZoom));

    map.fitBounds(mapBounds);
    L.tileLayer('tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg', {
      minZoom: mapMinZoom, maxZoom: mapMaxZoom,
      bounds: mapBounds,
      attribution: 'Fraser Island',
      noWrap: true          
    }).addTo(map);
  }

</script>
<style>
  html, body, #map { width:100%; height:480px; margin:0; padding:0; }
</style>
```

Here is the code for the body up until the map page:

```
<body onLoad="init()">
<!--Home Page Start-->
<div data-role="page" id="Home">
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
<a href="#Home" class="button" data-icon="home">Home</a>
<h1>Home Screen</h1>
</div>
<div></div>
<div data-role="content">
<center><div class="ui-grid-a" >
<div class="ui-block-a"><center><a href="#CustomMap"><img src="img/map_button.png" width="66" height="69" alt=""/></a><br>Map</center>          
</div>
</div></center>
</div>
</div>
<!--Home Page End-->
<!--Map Page Start-->
<div data-role="page" id="CustomMap">
<div data-role="header">
<a href="#Home" class="button" data-icon="home">Home</a>
<h1>Map</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">

<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 480px"></div>

</div>
</div>
<!--Map Page End-->
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE**

So based on the feedback I got it working on Android devices prior to Android version 4.4.2 but it doesn't work on 4.4.2 - not sure why it won't work on 4.4.2

The problem still exists, if I refresh the page the map works fine but it doesn't work on first load. For now I have including a small workaround by reloading the page as soon as it's loaded. I've managed to keep markers working while doing this, so everything is functioning as intended with this workaround but I would still love to get it to work on first load.

Here's the updated script:

Placed just before `</head>`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/leaflet.css" />
<script src="js/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="js/FunctionButton.js"></script> 
<script src="js/marker.js"></script>
<script>
var curMark = localStorage.getItem("mark");
var map;
  function init() {
    var mapMinZoom = 0;
    var mapMaxZoom = 3;
    map = L.map('map', {
      maxZoom: mapMaxZoom,
      minZoom: mapMinZoom,
      crs: L.CRS.Simple
    }).setView([0, 0], mapMaxZoom);

    document.getElementById('map').style.display = 'block';

    var mapBounds = new L.LatLngBounds(
        map.unproject([0, 2048], mapMaxZoom),
        map.unproject([2048, 0], mapMaxZoom));

    map.fitBounds(mapBounds);


    L.tileLayer('tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg', {
      minZoom: mapMinZoom, maxZoom: mapMaxZoom,
      bounds: mapBounds,
      attribution: 'Fraser Island',
      noWrap: true   
    }).addTo(map);

    var btn = L.functionButtons([{ content: '&circlearrowright;' }],       {position: 'topright'});
    btn.on('clicked', function(data) {
        if( data.idx == 0 ) {
            location.reload();
        };
    });
    map.addControl(btn);

    map.on('click', function(e) {
        <!--alert("Lat, Lon : " + e.latlng.lat + ", " + e.latlng.lng)
    });

    var micon = L.icon({
        iconUrl: 'img/marker_hole.png',
        iconSize: [25,41],
        iconAnchor: [12,35],
        popupAnchor: [0,-35]
    });
    var mark1 = new marker(-109.875, 111.75, micon, map);
    var mark2 = new marker(-51, 126.375, micon, map);
    var mark3 = new marker(-77.625, 140.75, micon, map);
    var mark4 = new marker(-92.875, 120.875, micon, map);
    var mark5 = new marker(-107.625, 132.375, micon, map);
    var mark6 = new marker(-134.125, 121.25, micon, map);
    var mark7 = new marker(-145.875, 107.875, micon, map);
    var mark8 = new marker(-147.625, 100, micon, map);
    var mark9 = new marker(-167.5, 103.75, micon, map);
    var mark10 = new marker(-183.625, 105.375, micon, map);
    var marks = [mark1,
                 mark2,
                 mark3,
                 mark4,
                 mark5,
                 mark6,
                 mark7,
                 mark8,
                 mark9,
                 mark10
                 ];

    if (curMark !== null){
        var cm = curMark.split(",")
        var zoomAt = new L.LatLng(cm[0],cm[1])
        map.setView(zoomAt, 3)
        localStorage.removeItem("mark")
        for (i=0; i < marks.length; i++){
            if (marks[i].getLatLng() == zoomAt.toString()){

            }
            else{
                marks[i].remove();
            }
        }
    }

    L.Util.requestAnimFrame(map.invalidateSize,map,!1,map._container);

  }

 $(window).load(init);

function goToMap(markId){
    localStorage.setItem("mark", markId);
}

</script>
```

In the Body tag:

```
<body  onbeforeunload="return window.location.reload(true)">
```

The div for the map page:

```
<!--Map Page Start-->
<div data-role="page" id="FraserMap">
<div data-role="header">
<a href="#Home" class="button" data-icon="home">Home</a>
<h1>Map</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">

<div id="map">
<script>
$('#FraserMap').bind('pageshow', function(){

    if (!localStorage.getItem("reload")) {
        localStorage.setItem("reload", "true");
        location.reload();
    }
    else {
        localStorage.removeItem("reload");
    }

    if (!localStorage.getItem("mark")) {
    }
    else {
        curMark = localStorage.getItem("mark");
    }
});
</script>
</div>

</div>
</div>
<!--Map Page End-->
```

Comment: Why not use jQuery to call the onload.  `$(window).load(init);` See if it helps

Comment: This helped with part of my solution, it's working on pre-4.4.2 devices but not on 4.4.2 version of android. Updated post with new script.

Answer (score 0):

When you go to the page where you have to set up the map, trigger this line there

```
L.Map.invalidateSize();
```

Comment: This actually helped me work my way to a solution, it's working on most devices I tested on but not on Android 4.4.2 - now just need to figure out what's going on there - updated the original post with my new script.